# Passing 2d arrays in typescript and the empty shadow array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

Found an issue and I can't get my head around it, almost looks like typescript (or java or node) is guessing when accessing the array.

When passing (and accessing) 2d arrays and promises are involved, there seems to be some issues with what is in the array. the array in this case is

```
 [
    [id, data]
    [id, data]
    [id, data]
]
```

The original script uses a number of structures, all the same style though, an array of arrays of data entries to be sent to a database.

To remove any external libraries and try to isolate the issue, I wrote the below example to illustrate:

```
const targetID: string = "SetTarget";

async function arrayProcessor(targe: string, data:Array<any>){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        console.log("Got "+ data.length " items");
        console.log("And the data I got was" + data);
        console.log(data);

    })
}

async function arrayLoad(){
    var dataArray : Array<any> =[];
    var dataIn : Array<any> =[];
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        dataIn.id = "1";

        dataIn.profileName = "Normal";
        dataArray.push(dataIn);
        dataIn = [];

        dataIn.id = "2";
        dataIn.profileName = "User";
        dataArray.push(dataIn);
        dataIn = [];
        dataIn.id = "3";
        dataIn.profileName = "KingKong";
        dataArray.push(dataIn);
        dataIn = [];

        console.log("Sending back " + dataArray);
        resolve (dataArray);
    }
}


async function loadManager() {
    const dataReturned = await arrayLoad();
    console.log("From promise I got" + dataReturned)
    const dataPRocessed = await arrayProcessor(targetID, dataReturned);
}


loadManager();
```

And the output is:

```
Sending back ,,
From promise I got,,
Got 3  items
And the data I got was,,
[ [ id: '1', profileName: 'Normal' ],
  [ id: '2', profileName: 'User' ],
  [ id: '3', profileName: 'KingKong' ] ]
```

After a lot of messing about, and more than once thinking that typescript was developed because the world hates me, I figured out that. If I call `console.log("Got this data " + data);` it returns ", , , ", but if I call
`console.log("Got this data"); console.log(data);`
It returns the array. and it seems like there are some other times when it gets this "ghost" array, which it probably isn't but I do not understand why?

And it seems consistent. And looking at the java code compiled from ts (its identical):

```
async function arrayProcessor(targe, data) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log("Got " + data.length, " items");
        console.log("And the data I got was" + data);
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

Bit of background, I need to write a synchronous data loading script, because it's all going into a relational database and it is a significant amount of data, so if I try to load the whole thing, java (or node) falls over with a memory dump. So I wrote a script that uses streams to read, and promises to control the flow to the data. This is not that script, but I wrote this to recreate the problem, but it looks like I recreated the same issue, sometimes I get the right data back from the array, sometimes I get just empty references.

Comment: java and javascript aren't the same thing.

Comment: This needs to be a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Excluding the 3rd party libraries does not help.